# Simplify power series expression

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have $z = -1 + \sum\limits_{\mu=1}^\infty \frac{\mu^{\mu-1}}{\mu!}x^\mu$ and our goal is to find $\frac{dz}{z}$.

$dz = \sum\limits_{\mu=1}^\infty \mu \frac{\mu^{\mu-1}}{\mu!}x^{\mu-1}dx$, but what to do next? I can't see any way how to simplify $\frac{dz}{z}$.

This is not a part of homework task, so feel free to show your calculations if you have any idea how to do it. Computer algebra systems like Wolfram Mathematica aren't suitable for this because from time to time I need to work with such expressions, so it it interesting for me how to calculate it manually.

Comment: Are you trying to express $dx$ in terms of $dz\,$? Is it part of a change of variable?

Comment: Vice versa, I have expression for $z$ in terms of $x$ and want to achieve an expression for $\frac{dz}{z}$ in terms of $x$ and $dx$.

Comment: I don't understand what $\;\frac{dz}z\;$ can possibly mean...I know $\;\frac{df}h\;$ , when $\;f\;$ is a function of the variable $\;h\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio. He is writing dz when he should be writing dz/dx, as seen in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sure that, if you never faced it, it is not easy to identify that $$ \sum\limits_{\mu=1}^\infty \frac{\mu^{\mu-1}}{\mu!}x^\mu=-W(-x)$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). So $$z=-1-W(-x)\implies z'=-\left(W(-x)\right)'=-\frac{W(-x)}{1+x (W(-x))}$$ from which $$\frac{z'}z=\frac{W(-x)}{x (1+W(-x))^2}=-\frac{1+z}{x\,z^2}$$

**Edit**

Let us make a numerical check for $x=\frac 1 {10}$ using only $10$ terms in the summation (this truncation leads to an error of almost $10^{-8}$ for the value of $z$) and numerical derivatives (using cental differences).

What we find is $$z\left(\frac 1 {10}\right)=-\frac{322298204032799}{362880000000000}$$ $$z\left(\frac {101} {1000}\right)=-\frac{321840675528184858662436394476379}{362880000000000000000000000000000}$$ $$z\left(\frac {99} {1000}\right)=-\frac{569231939128545995396324452363}{640000000000000000000000000000}$$ $$z'\left(\frac 1 {10}\right)=\frac{456916978850360363639785006721}{362880000000000000000000000000}$$So, for this value of $x$ $$\frac{z'}z=-\frac{456916978850360363639785006721}{322298204032799000000000000000}\approx -1.417683912$$ while $$-\frac{1+z}{x\,z^2}=-\frac{147263221205778988800000000000}{103876132322767733587067774401} \approx -1.417681020$$

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely what I need. But can you write more carefully why the derivative is $z' = -\frac{W(-x)}{1+x(W(-x))}$? I can see on Wikipedia that $\frac{dW}{dz} = \frac{W(z)}{z(1+W(z))}$ which seems to me not being the same thing.

Comment: @Hasek. Applying the chain rule gives the result.

Comment: @Hasek. Sorry ! I made a typo in the last expression. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is very confusing, but perhaps I understood something...and also using greek letters as summation index, and even not-so-usual-ones doesn't help much:

$$dz=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{n!}x^{n-1}=\frac nx(z+1)$$